# how to set linux machine fully qualified hostname to an environment variable in ant build.xml

Tags: shell, ant, environment-variables, build.xml

I have an ant `build.xml`.

I am trying to set the fully qualified hostname of the machine(ex: "abc-us.xyz.com") to an environment variable in an ant  and then trying to use that environment variable everywhere.

But am unable to do so.

As of now what i have tried is:

```
    <target name="get-fqdn">
    <echo>Getting the fully qualified hostname of the machine</echo>
    <exec executable="/bin/bash">
    <env key="FQDN" value="hostname-f"/>
    </exec>
    </target>
```

According to the above code, I am hoping that it will set the value of the `hostname -f` to the environment variable `FQDN`.

Then i have another target:

```
    <target name="get-database" depends="init,get-fqdn">
    <echo>Getting the database*************</echo>
    <echo>$FQDN</echo>
    </target>
```

In this second target, I am trying to access the environment variable 
`FQDN`, that has been already set in the first target.

But it's not working. Please help

I am not getting the value of the `FQDN` in the second target when I `echo` it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, any `<exec>` invocation will run in its own shell, thus any environment variable you set in this invocation will exist only in this shell and not in the parent shell (Ant's). You need a way to store the value of the environment variable in a way that will persist accross shell invocations, for example in a properties file:

```
<target name="get-fqdn">
  <exec executable="/bin/bash">
    <env key="FQDN" value="some_host.com"/>
    <arg value="-c"/>
    <arg line="echo FQDN=$FQDN > fqdn.properties"/>
  </exec>
</target>
```

Then all you have to do is load this properties file and make the properties it contains available to Ant:

```
<target name="get-database" depends="get-fqdn">
  <property file="fqdn.properties"/>
  <echo message="retrieved FQDN=${FQDN}"/>
</target>
```